# Android APP crashes while Loading the ads

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, ads

I am trying to make a social media application. I am trying to insert ads in between the posts.
In the below code when running app crashes while executing the adaptor.
i have added the adaptor code. sorry for the big code. when i comment the  ads and run, post is coming properly. problem is when i include the ad code app crashes without any error. sometimes its running continuously.

```
class NewpostAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val Post: ArrayList<Newpost>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
{
    private var firebaseUser:FirebaseUser? =null

    companion object{
        //TAG
        private const val TAG ="PRODUCT_TAG"

        //there will be 2 view type 1 for the actual content and 2 for the native ad

        private const val VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT =0
        private const val VIEW_TYPE_AD=1


    }



override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    val view :View



      if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_post,parent,false)
          return HolderProduct(view)
      }

      else{
          //inflate/return row_native_ad.xml
          view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_native_ad,parent,false)
         return HolderNativeAd(view)

      }


}



override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
  firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser




      if (getItemViewType(position)== VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT) {

           val post = Post[position]

            val holderProduct =holder as HolderProduct

            Picasso.get().load(post.getPostimage()).into(holderProduct.postImage)

            publisherInfo(
                holderProduct.profileImage,
                holderProduct.userName,
                holderProduct.publisheruser,
                    post.getPublisher()
            )





        }

           if (getItemViewType(position)== VIEW_TYPE_AD) {


            val adLoader  = AdLoader.Builder(context ,context.getString(R.string.native_ad_id_test))
                .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNativeAdLoaded: ")

                    //Ad is loaded,show it

                    //instance of our HolderNativeAd to access UI views of row_Native_ad.xml
                    val holderNativeAd = holder as HolderNativeAd
                    displayNativeAd(holderNativeAd,nativeAd)
                }
                .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {

                    override fun onAdClicked() {
                        super.onAdClicked()
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAdClicked: ")
                    }

                    override fun onAdClosed() {
                        super.onAdClosed()
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAdClosed: ")
                    }
})
                .withNativeAdOptions(NativeAdOptions.Builder().build()).build()

            adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

        }


    }
 private fun displayNativeAd(holderNativeAd: NewpostAdapter.HolderNativeAd, nativeAd: NativeAd) {
        /*------Get Ad assets from the NativeAd Object-----*/

        val headLine = nativeAd.headline
        val body  = nativeAd.body
        val callToAction = nativeAd.callToAction
        val icon = nativeAd.icon
        val price = nativeAd.price
        val store = nativeAd.store
        val starRating = nativeAd.starRating
        val advertiser = nativeAd.advertiser
        val mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent

        /*-----Same assets aren't guaranteed to be in every nativeAd,so we need to check before displaying item-----*/

        if (headLine==null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_headline.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_headline.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_headline.text=headLine

        }

        if (body==null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_body.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_body.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_body.text=body

        }


        if (icon == null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_app_icon.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_app_icon.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_app_icon.setImageDrawable(icon.drawable)

        }
        if (starRating == null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_stars.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_stars.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_stars.rating=starRating.toFloat()

        }
        if (price==null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_price.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_price.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_price.text=price

        }
        if (store==null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_store.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_store.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_store.text=store

        }
        if (advertiser==null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_advertiser.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_advertiser.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_advertiser.text=advertiser

        }
        if (mediaContent==null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.media_view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.media_view.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.media_view.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
            holderNativeAd.media_view.setMediaContent(mediaContent)

        }
        if (callToAction==null){
            //no content ,hide view
            holderNativeAd.ad_call_to_action.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        else{
            //have content ,show view
            holderNativeAd.ad_call_to_action.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            // set data
            holderNativeAd.ad_call_to_action.text=callToAction
            //handle ad button click
            holderNativeAd.native_Ad_View.callToActionView=holderNativeAd.ad_call_to_action

        }
        // add nativeAd  the NativeView
        holderNativeAd.native_Ad_View.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return  Post.size
}

   override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        //logic to display Native Ad between content
        if (position % 5 == 0){
            //after 5 items .show native ad
            return VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT
        }
        else{
            //return the view type VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT to show content
            return  VIEW_TYPE_AD
        }

    }



    inner class HolderProduct( itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


       val profileImage: CircleImageView
       val postImage: ImageView
       val likeButton: ImageView
       val commentButton: ImageView
       val saveButton: ImageView
       val userName: TextView
      val likesuser: TextView
       val publisheruser: TextView
       val descriptionuser: TextView
       val commentsuser: TextView

       init {
           profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image_newPost)
           postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_home2)
           likeButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_like_button)
           commentButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image_comment_button)
           saveButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_save_comment_button)
           userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_search)
           likesuser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes_user)
           publisheruser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher_user)
           descriptionuser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_user)
           commentsuser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments_user)
       }


   }
    //ViewHolder class for row_native_ad.xml

    inner class HolderNativeAd(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        //init UI Views
        val ad_app_icon :ImageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_app_icon)
        val ad_headline:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline)
        val ad_advertiser:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser)
        val ad_stars: RatingBar =itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_stars)
        val ad_body:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body)
        val media_view: MediaView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.media_view)
        val ad_price:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price)
        val ad_store:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store)
        val ad_call_to_action: Button =itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action)
        val native_Ad_View: NativeAdView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_Ad_View)

    }



}
```

Comment: Apps never crash without an error. You might have LogCat set to filter out your app.

Comment: app crashes in this line. val native_Ad_View: NativeAdView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_Ad_View). 

i tried all type of settings like changing the filters and category to verbose and restarted the development machine.  nothing worked out am not getting the crash report.

Comment: earlier i tried this code with Activity . it works well but now am calling this adapter from fragment. not sure could that have any impact.

Comment: Your very first priority is to get your logging to work correctly. You'll never be able to finish developing an app if you can't see your stack traces. Maybe search for reasons why you might not see stack traces in Android Studio.